# How to feed the json value in text box using jQuery AutoComplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

I have the following value representation of an actual JSON object returned from my controller:

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var customers = [{"name":"Urban Development","id":1},{"name":"Ball Corporation","id":2},{"name":"Apache Software Foundation","id":3},{"name":"The Coca-Cola Company","id":4},{"name":"Discovery Communications, Inc.","id":5},{"name":"Electronic Data Systems","id":6},{"name":"FreeWave Technologies, Inc.","id":7}] ;
    $("#customer").autocomplete({ source: customers });
</script>
```

html:

```
<label for="customer">Customer Name</label>
<input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" >
```

I dont know how to do this so any1 can help me.

**Updated**
Model page

```
public function getEmp(){
$db = Loader::db();     
return $db->GetArray("select emp_id, emp_name as label, emp_name as value, emp_doj from employee_master");}
```

Controller page

```
$employee = employeeinfo::getEmp();
$this->set('employee', $employee);
```

view page
 script

```
$(function() {
var dataEmp = <?php echo json_encode($employee); ?>;

/* my json value like this
[
{"id": "2","label": "S Kumar ","value": "S Kumar ","emp_doj": "2013-07-02"}, 
{"id": "3","label": "Cj Ramki ","value": "Cj Ramki ","emp_doj": "2013-07-03"}, 
{"id": "4","label": "V Sudarsanam","value": "V Sudarsanam","emp_doj": "2011-06-06"}, 
{"id": "9","label": "S Kamal","value": "S Kamal", "emp_doj": "2013-07-17"},
{"id": "15","label": "R Malani","value": "R Malani","emp_doj": "2014-01-03"}
];*/
$( "#pAdminName" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: dataEmp,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#hd" ).val( ui.item.emp_id );
        return false;
    }       
});
});
```

html

```
<?php echo $form->text('pAdminName',$pAdminName,array('placeholder'=>'Enter or select a name from list')) ?>
<input type="hidden" id="hd" name="hd" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding another answer as this is a different approach than what was before

```
   $("#field").autocomplete({
        source: customers,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#field_id").val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
```

I have added a field to show the id , so that you can fetch it to do whatever manipulation you want to do.

here is the link to the fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/137/**

**Updated answer on doubt**

Are you sure the value of dataEmp is in the same format as I have mentioned in the fiddle. you can check it in firebug console.

I think your json array is coming in the format of `{"name":"Urban Development","id":1}` wheras it should be `{"value":"Urban Development", "id":1}`. Change name to value.

Comment: Hi i have problem textbox is not show the list while i am using json value.

Comment: have you included the css http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css file on the top ?

Comment: No, now i have another problem. if i am using to mouse to select the name in the list is not selected. may i know why?

Comment: are you sure the value of dataEmp is in the same format as I have mentioned in the fiddle. you can check it in firebug console.

Comment: Yes sure the same format.. if i using enter key in list is selected but if use mouse click not work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46403/discussion-between-aelor-and-kumar-shanmugam)

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding autocomplete take two params, an array of objects with two properties value and data { value : "Urban Development", data : 1 } and a call back function

So you would need to parse your Json into this format first;

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsondata); 
var autocomplete_data = [];
for(var prop in json){
    autocomplete_data.push({ value : json[prop].name, data : json[prop].id });
}

 $("#customer").autocomplete(autocomplete_data, function(){ this.value = "blah" });
```

Comment: @KumarShanmugam, You would need to add your own logic in as well chap, this.value = "blah" isnt going to do anything now is it. You would need to make sure that the autocomplete_data array is in the format you require. console.log(autocomplete_data); and that the callback function is doing something like prepopulating the input value with what you want. Cant do it all for you, unless you want to pay me ;)

Comment: I'm not expect all those from you.. at same time i am not familiar with jquery...  thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery autocomplete in your case.

The trick here to do is to convert your json object into array of names so that your autocomplete works

like this :

```
var newarr = [];
var customers = [{"name":"Urban Development","id":1},{"name":"Ball Corporation","id":2},{"name":"Apache Software Foundation","id":3},{"name":"The Coca-Cola Company","id":4},{"name":"Discovery Communications, Inc.","id":5},{"name":"Electronic Data Systems","id":6},{"name":"FreeWave Technologies, Inc.","id":7}] ;
for (i=0; i<customers.length; ++i) {
  newarr.push(customers[i].name);
}
```

now your `newarr` has the array necessary for doing the autocompletion. So you can just use the following code to get your thing done

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {

var newarr = [];
var customers = [{"name":"Urban Development","id":1},{"name":"Ball Corporation","id":2},{"name":"Apache Software Foundation","id":3},{"name":"The Coca-Cola Company","id":4},{"name":"Discovery Communications, Inc.","id":5},{"name":"Electronic Data Systems","id":6},{"name":"FreeWave Technologies, Inc.","id":7}] ;
for (i=0; i<customers.length; ++i) {
  newarr.push(customers[i].name);
}

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: newarr
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as mentioned in the tutorial of jquery and a live demo also http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Cheers !!

Comment: Yeah its working as autocomplete, but how to get corresponding id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use _renderItem method plus select callback:

```
    var customers = [{"name":"Urban Development","id":1},
        {"name":"Ball Corporation","id":2},{"name":"Apache Software Foundation","id":3},
        {"name":"The Coca-Cola Company","id":4},{"name":"Discovery Communications,Inc.","id":5},
        {"name":"Electronic Data Systems","id":6},{"name":"FreeWave Technologies, Inc.","id":7}] ;
    $("#customer").autocomplete({ 
        source: customers,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#customer").val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        } 
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).
        _renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" )
            .attr( "data-value", item.id )
            .append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.name ) )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Comment: I tried the same code form jquery ui but its not work to my json value

Comment: Have you got a javascript error? Can you please look in console?